# vibration pattern in iphone application

Tags: iphone

i want to apply different vibration pattern in iphone application i have applied
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); 
-i have done one way by applying this in loop so it can played in long duration but,
i want to know if any other way can apply different vibration pattern ,becuase there is   only one parameter kSystemSoundID_Vibrate (my device is not jailbroken)

Comment: I found that this is not possible right now